# How to determine when bodies in display stop moving in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics-engine

I have some bodies moving in display using physics. I want to determine when bodies stop moving so as to call a function to take an action.
I tried a function like so:

```
function ball:stopMove ()
    if condition then
        print("Game Over!!!")
    end
end
```

This do not get invoked. how can I do this correctly?

Comment: Please include what you have actually tried- for instance, what is `condition`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/05/01/tutorial-property-callbacks/) to see how to implement your own callbacks. Basically you can create a proxy table that acts as a filter, screening for certain actions and acting on those.

If you don't want to do that, assuming you created a [physics body](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/physicsBodies/index.htm), the function you are looking for is [`object:getLinearVelocity`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/physicsBodies/index.html#objectgetlinearvelocity). If the object's x and y velocity are zero, the body has stopped moving. You would, of course, need to check for this every update.

Alternatively, you can calculate this yourself if you aren't using a physics body. All you need to do is keep track of the object's last x and y positions, and if the values are the same, the object has not moved since the lasted update.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to keep polling after equal intervals that the bodies stopped moving?

Comment: @user3547555 I'm not sure what you mean, although I've updated my answer to include a relevant link that I think will be the solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any movement related events. So I guess you have to frequently poll the objects velocity for being zero.